# Getting raw XML parameter in JAX-WS webservice method

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, cxf

How to achieve something like that:

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "ru.citc.techtest.cxfconcepts.HelloWorld")
public class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloWorld {

    public String sayHi(DOMSource xml) {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

I need a raw XML for processing (SAX or DOM). In same time I want to leverage existing method routing of JAX-WS.(I use Apache CXF)
Returned value may be any type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this will work:

```
@WebService(wsdlLocation = "....")
@DataBinding(org.apache.cxf.databinding.source.SourceDataBinding.class)
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE) 
public class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloWorld {
     public Source sayHi(Source xml) {
        return xml;
    }
}
```

By default, you should get a StaxSource (which is a subclass of SAXSource) so you can pass that into your XML processing library and such.  You can return any subclass of Source.   However, you can also be more specific and use:

```
public Source sayHi(DOMSource xml)
```

if you know you need it as a DOM.    I actually think:

```
public Source sayHi(XMLStreamReader xml)
```

would work as well.

Comment: Daniel, thanx once more. Typpo Souce -> Source